# Add styled-jsx to ejected create-react-app config

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I know adding styled-jsx to a normal create-react-app is currently not possible. So I ejected it and now i'm trying to modify webpack.config.dev.js to include it, but been clueless as to where to put the plugin.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out all I had to modify was to add the plugins array into the part in webpack.config.dev.js (and webpack.config.prod.js) where the JS is processed with babel:

```
// Process JS with Babel.
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
                    include: paths.appSrc,
                    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                    options: {
                        // Add styled-jsx loader
                        plugins: ['styled-jsx/babel'],
                        // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                        // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                        // directory for faster rebuilds.
                        cacheDirectory: true
                    }
                },
```

> !! Edited on
>   01/02/2019 !!

Actually on `react-scripts` version 2.1.2, we have just one file to "dev | prod" named: `_project\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js`.

This file has follow comment, and begin an object with `options` prop.

Inside this prop, we have an array called `plugins`, so we need to add our plugin here, see bellow:

```
// Process application JS with Babel.
// The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
{


    // code code code
    // code code code

    plugins: [
        [
            require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
            {
                loaderMap: {
                svg: {
                    ReactComponent:
                    '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                },
                },
            },
        ],
        ['styled-jsx/babel']
    ],
}
```